# Package installed correctly (?), but keeps showing up as to-update

Tags: package-management, mongodb

I just upgraded my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04. Everythings seems to work fine, but one package keeps popping up in update list constantly.

```
20:28:28 ~
$ LANG=C sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease                                                                                       
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                    
Hit:4 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release                                                                   
Hit:5 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                        
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]                                         
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                    
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                           
Hit:10 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                     
Hit:12 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x xenial InRelease                                               
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease             
Hit:14 https://deb.opera.com/opera-developer stable InRelease                        
Hit:16 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
Fetched 94.5 kB in 0s (119 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
20:28:45 ~
$ LANG=C sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mongodb-org
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3556 B of archives.
After this operation, 12.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 401253 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org_3.2.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org (3.2.10) over (3.2.10) ...
Setting up mongodb-org (3.2.10) ...
20:28:51 ~
$ LANG=C sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mongodb-org
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3556 B of archives.
After this operation, 12.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 401253 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org_3.2.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org (3.2.10) over (3.2.10) ...
Setting up mongodb-org (3.2.10) ...
20:31:04 ~
$
```

Where can I look for hint? Mongo is working fine.